# Using Print settings with Chromium Embedded Framework 3

Tags: delphi, chromium, chromium-embedded

I'm using the [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef) in my Delphi XE7 application through the [DCEF3](https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3) version.

Loading web pages through the TChromium object works fine. I also managed to get printing to work.

Problem: I don't seem to find how I can set the specific printing settings through the **TCefPrintSettings** in ceflib. The class is [explained here](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefPrintSettings.html), but I don't seem to be able to find out how to use it.

Anyone here that can point me in the right direction? That would be very much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`CefPrintSettings` is relevant in the context of `CefPrintHandler` which is only used when running on `Linux`. To my knowledge there is little control over print settings in `CEF`.

http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefPrintHandler.html

See a similar question here http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=13036&p=26102